# multiplot for gtable objects

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, gtable, grob

The [`multiplot` function is defined here in the cookbook](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_(ggplot2)/)

Consider the following graphs.

```
p1 = ggplot(mtcars,aes(y=mpg, x=cyl)) + geom_point()
p2 = ggplot(mtcars,aes(y=disp, x=cyl)) + geom_point()
multiplot(p1,p2, layout=matrix(1:2,nrow=1))
```

[image]

I'd like to manipulate (with function `DoStuff`) the plot as a `gtable` object rather than as a `ggplot` object.

```
g1 = ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p1))
g1 = DoStuff(g1)
g2 = ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p1))
g2 = DoStuff(g2)
```

I can print a gtable with `grid.draw`.

**How can I modify the multiplot function, so that it also accepts `gtable` objects and not just `ggplot` objects?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in my [somewhat biased view](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/egg/vignettes/Ecosystem.html#alternative-options) you'd be better off using

```
gridExtra::grid.arrange(g1,g2, ncol=2)
```

but to answer your question:

change

```
print(plots[[i]], vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = matchidx$row,
                                layout.pos.col = matchidx$col))
```

to something like

```
  if(inherits(plots[[i]], "gg")) {

    print(plots[[i]], vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = matchidx$row,
                                    layout.pos.col = matchidx$col))

  } else if(inherits(plots[[i]], "gtable")) {

    pushViewport(viewport(layout.pos.row = matchidx$row, 
                          layout.pos.col = matchidx$col))
    grid.draw(plots[[i]])
    upViewport()
  }
```

and call it as before,

```
g1 <- ggplotGrob(p1)
g2 <- ggplotGrob(p2)
multiplot(g1,g2, layout=matrix(1:2,nrow=1))
```